# Apache Drill: Hash join does not support schema changes Error on extra column

Tags: apache-drill, mapr

When querying a table in Apache Drill, i get this error:

> SYSTEM ERROR: SchemaChangeException: Hash join does not support schema
>   Changes.

The query is like below:

```
Select abc, xyz, proxyip from D_UNIV_TABLE where SUB_NUM in (select SUB_NUM from TABLE_B);
```

The same query works fine when proxyip column is removed from select clause.

```
Select abc, xyz from D_UNIV_TABLE where SUB_NUM in (select SUB_NUM from TABLE_B);
```

proxyip has null values and ip addresses. How can addition of a column give Schema change exception?

MapR Apache Drill Version: 1.10

Comment: It would be helpful if you could also attach the plan - explain plan including all attributes for select ...

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a bug. Please create a Jira ticket and provide the plan, data and logs
https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/DRILL

The possible workaround is to use `CAST(proxyip AS <data type>)`.